# How best to implement atomic update on a file inside a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sh, flock

I have a script which has multiple functions, running in parallel which checks a file and updates it frequently. I dont want two functions to update the file at the same time and create an issue. So what will be the best way to have an atomic update. I have the following so far.

```sh
counter(){
    a=$1
    while true;do
        if [ ! -e /tmp/counter.lock ];then
            touch /tmp/counter.lock
            curr_count=`cat /tmp/count.txt`
            n_count=`echo "${curr_count}  + $a" | bc`
            echo ${n_count} > /tmp/count.txt
            rm -fv /tmp/counter.lock
            break
        fi
        sleep 1 
    done
}
```

I am not sure how to convert my function to use flock, since it uses file descriptor and it might create issue if I call this function multiple time(or I think so.)

Comment: This is the most basic use case of flock. Have you tried to search existing answers around flock?

Answer (score 0):

`flock` works by letting anyone *open* the lock file, but blocking if someone else *locks* it first. In your code, a second process could test for the existence of the lock after you see it doesn't exist but before you actually create it.

```
counter () {
  a=$1
  {
     flock -s 200
     read current_count < /tmp/count.xt
     ...
     echo new_count > /tmp/count.txt
  } 200> /tmp/counter.lock
}
```

Here, two processes can open `/tmp/counter.lock` for writing. In one process, `flock` will get the lock and exit immediately. In the other, `flock` will block until the first process releases the lock by closing its file descriptor once the command block completes.